# Gradle subprojects refresh removes other dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I have following project structure:

```
rootProject.name = 'toolbox-backend'
include 'toolbox-components-executor'
include 'toolbox-components-toolsyncer'
include 'toolbox-components-toolconfigparser'
```

toolsyncer i.e. has the dependency for the jgit library. While trying to edit the code in the service java file I see that IntelliJ shows the resolve in red - so it isn't found.

I found out that this happens when I resolve all projects at the same time. The **toolsyncer** subprojects shortly resolved the dependency but gets its dependencies removed as soon as the next subprojects starts to resolved and therefore **removes** the jgit dependency since it does not need it.

Whats the best practise here? Declare all dependencies needed in the root project?